# .exe file fails to read a VideoStream from a camera connected via rtsp?

Tags: python, pyinstaller, rtsp, opencv

I have a little project that should read VideosStream from **rtsp** camera to do some other tasks. I could run its original *hc_yolo_all.py* file without any issue. However, after making an executable file with `pyinstaller --onefile hc_yolo_all.py`, it couldn't derive VideoStream and gave the error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hc_yolo_all.py", line 60, in <module>
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4044: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'

[7340] Failed to execute script hc_yolo_all.
```

It is seen that `frame = cv2.resize(frame, (416,416))`, line 60, of  *hc_yolo_all.py* is receiving an empty frame and therefore, output an error.

Where do you think the issue lies in?

I, to be honest, don't know whether it is related to opencv or rtsp or pyinstaller, so I've tagged those three.

Comment: You might just implement a simple if statement that applies cv2.resize only if received frame is not empty? This way you would be able to get all the rtsp VideoStream ignoring the empty incoming frames

Comment: @Employee, good point, but I mentioned I could run a program without any issue when I directly used .py file itself. Otherwise I wouldn't be able to do that. I tend to think that **.exe** file can't get access to the provided **rtsp** address

Answer (score 0):

Well, I could find a solution to my own question. It looks like we need to have a `opencv_ffmpegxx.dll` alongside with the `.exe` file. Here, `xx` should be the version of opencv when the `.py` was being made `.exe`. My `opencv` version was 3.4.3 (*even Error is showing above*), therefore, I put `opencv_ffmpeg343_64.dll` next to my `.exe`.

**How to find corresponding dll:** Look for the *C:\Users\username\Anaconda3\envs\envname\Lib\site-packages\cv2/* in case of using Anaconda.

Credits to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475130/capturing-rtsp-stream-fails-when-the-script-is-turned-into-a-standalone-executab)